# Or Interior.Color Statement Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I need help with an Or statement in VBA. I have a Conditional Format set where if a cell is highlighted red OR orange, prevent save.

```
For Each rng In Worksheets(1).UsedRange
If rng.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = vbRed Or rng.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = #FF9900 Then 'This is where the code is erroring, may be I'm not referring to the color correctly. 
    MsgBox ("Please correct any fields highlighted in red")
    Cancel = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
End If
Next rng
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `.DisplayFormat`

```
Sub test()

Dim Rng as Range

For Each Rng In Worksheets(1).UsedRange

If Rng.Interior.Color = vbRed Or Rng.Interior.Color = 49407 Then
    MsgBox ("Please correct any fields highlighted in red")
    Cancel = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub
End If

Next Rng

End Sub
```

Comment: Hmmmm... I'm still able to save when there are orange filled cells present.

Comment: Whats the RGB of the orange color?

Comment: Record a macro applying that color and change #FF9900 with the correct RGB